# strange behaviour with a foreach loop inside a while READ()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm a VFP developer thats trying to pick up C#. Figuring that the fastest way to learn is by doing, I gave myself a small project for practice.

**Objective**

Move some transactions from the "live" database into an archive database.

The general idea was:

- to get a list of "suitable" Jobs (parent) then to read() them one by
  one.
- use a foreach loop to process a list of child tables, inserting the
  new record in the History database followed by deleting the old one
  from the "live" table.
- move the actual Job (parent) to archive, then delete it from "live"

Things went OK at the start, then I suddenly hit a brick wall....

**Problem**

I have a variable called RefCombo that I used to store the parent's primary key, this is stored right after the `while (READ())` statement and just before the `foreach` loop.

In a test database of four records, the RefCombo field should have been:

while read() result: Job1

foreach childtable in my predefined list

- process ChildTable1
- process ChildTable2
- process ChildTable3
- process ChildTable4
- process ChildTable5

then repeating with Job2, Job3 and Job4.

What's driving me nuts is I'm getting this instead:

while read() result: Job1

foreach childtable in my predefined list

- process ChildTable1
- SKIP other ChildTables, RefCombo (primary key) becomes Job2, loops back to the `while read()`

The thing is, once it changes to Job2, it proceeds to work exactly like I expected, looping through every single child table for each remaining parent record.

I'm also getting a "The current TransactionScope is already complete." error every other time I'm running the web page. This happens at the `connection.open()` part at the start of the program but it's hard to pin down since it doesn't happen all the time.

I've posted the code at the bottom, its sorta longish for a casual glance but any help would be much appreciated. I've been working on this for 2 days and really can't afford any more hair loss, lol.

Any comments on my code would also be more that welcome, I'm REALLY new to C# and every bit helps :P

Thanks in advance.

```
#region Declaration
DateTime FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2011");
DateTime ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/03/2011");
string conStrSource = @"Data Source=HOME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCC_Live;Integrated Security=True";

// Declare a list of child tables to check and move together with the Job
List<String> TablesToMove = new List<String>();
    {
    TablesToMove.Add("JobItems");
    TablesToMove.Add("JobTerms");
    TablesToMove.Add("JobMessages");
    TablesToMove.Add("JobCalcs");
    TablesToMove.Add("JobContainers");
    TablesToMove.Add("JobMetrics");
    }
#endregion

#region Set SQL String
string QueryString =
    "SELECT " +
    "JobMaster.BranchID, JobMaster.JobNo, " +
    "JobMaster.ImportDate, PermitStatus.CurrentStatus " +
    "FROM JobMaster. " +
    "INNER JOIN PermitStatus ON " +
        "JobMaster.BranchID = PermitStatus.BranchID AND " +
        "JobMaster.JobNo = PermitStatus.JobNo " +
    "WHERE " +
        "(JobMaster.ImportDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate) AND " +
        "PermitStatus.currentStatus NOT IN ('HT0', 'HT1', 'HT2')";
#endregion

// Display on web page for reference
ASPxFromDate.Value = FromDate;
ASPxToDate.Value = ToDate;
ASPxMemo1.Value = QueryString;

#region Open Connection, Get List of filtered Master Jobs
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStrSource))
    {
        int JobCount = 0;
        ASPxListBox1.Items.Clear();
        ASPxListBox2.Items.Clear();
        ASPxListBox3.Items.Clear();
        ASPxListBox1.Columns.Clear(); 

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(QueryString, connection);
            {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FromDate", FromDate));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ToDate", ToDate));
            }
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader FilteredJobList = command.ExecuteReader();

#endregion

        try // Process MasterJob File
        {
        // Process individual jobs one by one so I won't tie up memory and have better logging
        while (FilteredJobList.Read())
            {
            #region Declare variables
            string RefCombo = (string)FilteredJobList[0] + (string)FilteredJobList[1]; //Get primary key
            JobCount = JobCount + 1;
            ASPxTextBox2.Value = JobCount;
            ASPxListBox2.Items.Add(RefCombo);
            #endregion

            // Start transaction scope
            TransactionScope TranScope = new TransactionScope();
                {
                try
                    {
                    // Loop through child tables
                    foreach (string CurrentTable in TablesToMove)
                        {
                        #region Transfer child tables
                        // update list so I know which part its working on
                        ASPxListBox1.Items.Add(CurrentTable);  
                        RefCombo = (string)FilteredJobList[0] + (string)FilteredJobList[1];
                        string RefTableNow = (string)CurrentTable;
                        bool CancelTrans = false;
                        MoveChild(ref RefCombo, ref RefTableNow, ref conStrSource, ref CancelTrans);
                            if (CancelTrans == false)
                                { //LogFailure();
                                break;
                                }
                        DelChild(ref RefCombo, ref RefTableNow, ref conStrSource, ref CancelTrans);
                            if (CancelTrans == false)
                                { //LogFailure();
                                break;
                                }
                        #endregion
                            // Remove remaing entries
                            //MoveLatestStatus();
                            //DeleteLatestStatus();
                            //MoveMasterJob();
                            //DeleteMasterJob();
                            //LogSuccess();
                            TranScope.Complete();
                        }
                catch
                    {
                    //LogFailure();
                    }
                }
            }
        finally
            {
                FilteredJobList.Close();
            }
        }
    }


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void MoveChild(ref string RefCombo, ref string CurrentTable, ref string conStrSource, ref bool CancelTrans)
    {
    #region Define Insert String
    string InsertSqlString =
        "INSERT INTO [MCC_History].[dbo].[" + @CurrentTable + "]" +
        " SELECT * FROM [MCC_Live].[dbo].[" + @CurrentTable + "] s" +
        " WHERE NOT EXISTS" +
        " (SELECT 1 FROM [MCC_History].[dbo].[" + @CurrentTable + "] t2" +
        " WHERE t2.BranchID + t2.JobNo = s.BranchID + s.JobNo)" +
        " AND s.BranchID + s.JobNo = @RefCombo";

    #endregion

    #region Open connection and execute query
    using (SqlConnection MoveConnect = new SqlConnection(conStrSource))
        {
        try
            {
            SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(InsertSqlString, MoveConnect);
                {
                InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RefCombo", RefCombo));
                }
            MoveConnect.Open();
            InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        catch
            {
            CancelTrans = true;
            }
        }
    #endregion
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void DeleteChild(ref string RefCombo, ref string CurrentTable, ref string conStrSource, ref bool CancelTrans)
    {
    #region Define Delete query
    string DeleteSqlString =
        " DELETE FROM [MCC_Live].[dbo].[" + @CurrentTable + "]" +
        " WHERE [MCC_Live].[dbo].[" + @CurrentTable + 
        "].BranchID + [MCC_DB].[dbo].[" + @CurrentTable + "].JobNo = @RefCombo";
    #endregion

    #region Execute Delete query
    using (SqlConnection MoveConnect = new SqlConnection(conStrSource))
        {
        try
            {
            SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(DeleteSqlString, MoveConnect);
                {
                InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RefCombo", RefCombo));
                }
            MoveConnect.Open();
            InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        catch
            {
            CancelTrans = true;
            }
        }
    #endregion
    }
```

Comment: "The current TransactionScope is already complete." error must have something to do with the asp.net setup. Some code is kept in memory while other code is not.

Chop up the code in smaller actions and multiple steps to drilldown to the error in the code. This huge list is too hard to walk trough.
You should also add the asp.net code that calls this code. It isn't really clear this way.

Comment: Will do, thanks :)

At least now I know where to start searching.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you have your `TranScope.Complete();` statement.  It is inside of your foreach loop and it belongs after your Foreach block exits.  You complete your transaction at the end of your first iteration of your list.  This prevents you from making any more commands through this transaction.